# how do I show/hide buttons based on certain conditions in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm trying to figure out how to hide my login/signup buttons if a user is signed in or out.

I've looked into VISIBILITY and GONE, either one will work. However, I can't find any tutorials that match what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here's some code snippets for what I'm trying to accomplish:

Edit from original post:

In authentication.dart (only functions):

```
loginUser(context) async {
  formkey.currentState.save();
  if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
    await _auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
        .catchError((e) {
          home.changeState(null);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Invalid email and/or password. Please try again",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
          timeInSecForIos: 5,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
    }).then((newUser) {
      var now = new DateTime.now();
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(newUser.uid)
          .collection('userInfo')
          .document('userInfo')
          .setData({
        'Last login': now,
      }).catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Update user failed: $e",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
            timeInSecForIos: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0
        );
      });
      welcomeUser();
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  }
  final user = await getSignedInUser();
  home.changeState(user);
}

getSignedInUser() async {

  mCurrentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  if(mCurrentUser == null || mCurrentUser.isAnonymous){
    return null;
  }
  else{
    return mCurrentUser;
  }
}

signOutUser () async{
  await _auth.signOut();
  final user = await getSignedInUser();
  home.changeState(user);
}



HomeScreen home; //create instance of homescreen class, so I could call my function
```

In loginScreen (piece to create button to login):

```
Expanded(
    child: OutlineButton(
       child: Text("Login "),
       onPressed: () =>
               loginUser(context)),
               flex: 1,
         ),
```

homeScreen class (omitted irrelevant functions):

```
class HomeScreen extends State<MyApp> {
  FirebaseUser currentUser; //not sure what to initialize this to upon loading app because user might still be signed in.
  final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("HikeLocator"), backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
          ),
          body: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Form(
                key: formkey,
                child:
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    distanceFromUser(),
                    lengthOfTrail(),
                    numOfResults(),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                    ),
                    submitButton(),
                   // loginButton(),
                    //signupButton(),
                    //logoutButton(),
                    //profile(),
                  ] + (currentUser == null ? [
                    loginButton(),
                    signupButton(),
                  ] : [ // logged in? show the following widgets
                  logoutButton(),
                  profile(),
                ]),
                ),
              )
          ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget loginButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      child: Text("Log In", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogInScreen()),
        );
      },
    );
  }



  Widget logoutButton(){
      return RaisedButton(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
        child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        onPressed: () async {
          await signOutUser();
        }
      );
  }
  Widget signupButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      child: Text("Sign Up", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpScreen()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  changeState(value){
    setState(() {
      this.currentUser = value;
    });
  }
}
```

I have a function I wrote called getSignedInUser(). If there is none, it returns null. I'm new to flutter. Specified above in comments show the buttons that are supposed to be visibile in certain cases. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with this:

```
Widget loginButton() {
  return getSignedInUser() == null
      ? RaisedButton(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
          child: Text("Log In", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogInScreen()),
            );
          },
        )
      : Container();
}
```

If the user is signed-in, return an empty container, otherwise, return the login button. You can do the same in other functions that return a widget.

You could also wrap your login button in `Opacity` widget and set `opacity` to 0.0 to make it hidden, but it will still occupy space.

**Update**: I've prepared the following example to demonstrate a simple login page. The `getUser` function simulates a function that authenticates the user and returns the username (after two seconds) if login is successful.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LoginPageState createState() {
    return new LoginPageState();
  }
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String user;

  Future<String> getUser() {
    return Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () {
        return "john";
      },
    );
  }

  void login() async {
    final user = await getUser();
    setState(() {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  void logout() {
    setState(() {
      this.user = null;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildLoginButton() {
    return user == null
        ? RaisedButton(
            onPressed: login,
            child: Text("Login"),
          )
        : Container();
  }

  Widget _buildLogoutButton() {
    return (user != null)
        ? RaisedButton(
            onPressed: logout,
            child: Text("Logout"),
          )
        : Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildLoginButton(),
            _buildLogoutButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm I've tried both attempts and running into additional problems. They appear to work initially, but getSignedInUser() function is async, so it always returns null initially. I tried making my logout widget async and calling signin = await getSignedInUser() and comparing with signin, but then I had to make it return Future<Widget> instead of just Widget. But the children of Widgets won't work with that. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mike1982 I updated my answer with an example. I hope it helps.

Comment: ah thank you. it makes sense logically, but all my button hiding should be done in home screen, so I attempted to write a function to change the state in homeScreen and pass the value null or a FirebaseUser. However, I get errors says changeState was called on null. When I tried to use ints (1 for logged in, 0 for not logged in), no changes are being applied. I updated my code from the original post to show some more code and logic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a workaround. Have my landing page as login, with a button that says continue as guest. When I click login, it take me back to homescreen, but I send a value into the constructor as 1. If I click continue as guest, it sends value of 0. Then I check if that value is 0 or 1 to determine if I should render the widgets. I'm having another issue dealing with formkeys and page routes, but I'll post a separate question on that. Thanks for your help guys